# Import secret key into GnuPg doesn't work?

Tags: gnupg, pgp

I would like to import a private key into GPG so I did:

```
gpg --allow-secret-key-import --import /path/to/key/key.asc
gpg: key 51D5DF493ECAFF88: "John Doe <john.doe@acme.com>" not changed
gpg: key 51D5DF493ECAFF88: secret key imported
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:              unchanged: 1
gpg:       secret keys read: 1
gpg:  secret keys unchanged: 1
```

But then, the key is not listed :

```
$ gpg --list-secret-keys | grep 51D5DF493ECAFF88
(nothing)
```

What's wrong?

```
$ gpg --list-packets /path/to/key/key.asc | grep dummy
(nothing)

$ gpg --version
gpg (GnuPG) 2.2.4
libgcrypt 1.8.1
```